# Joint distribution given marginals and correlation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to understand whether it is possible and if so then how to find a joint distribution given marginals and a correlation matrix.

In particular, suppose $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are discrete random variables. I am given their marginals $p_{X_{1}},\ldots,p_{X_{n}}$ and their correlation matrix. Can I construct (uniquely?) the joint $p_{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}}$?

I tried this for $n=2$, assuming each of the two random variables has two possible outcomes $a$ and $b>a$, and assuming that the marginals of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are the same given by $\mathbb{P}[X_{1}=a]=c$. Let $r$ be the correlation of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$. My Mathematica readily calculates unique joint distribution provided $c(1-r)<1$ and claims there is no joint otherwise.

How would I generalize to more random variables with more than two possible outcomes? What I do in Mathematica (calculate correlation from joint distribution and then solve for the joint distribution that gives $r$) does not generalize nicely. Also, are there some results that would tell me what I am doing can/cannot be done? Uniquely?

I tried reading StackExchange questions/answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77334/how-does-one-generally-find-a-joint-distribution-function-or-density-from-marg), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255427/joint-distribution-function-from-marginals?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664806/what-information-is-needed-to-determine-the-joint-probability-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447583/how-to-find-joint-pdf-given-pdf-of-two-continuous-random-variables), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499583/finding-a-distribution-given-marginals-and-correlation-matrix). But none of the answers help me forward. Also, I know that this question is trivial when the random variables are independent. So let's disregard that special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the joint distribution is not uniquely determined by the marginals.  The correlations only give second order moment information so are still not enough to pin down a unique joint distribution.

Adapting [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example) example from wiki, suppose $W$ is a random variable that takes values $-1,1$ with equal probability, and $X\sim N(0,1)$. Assume $X$ is independent of $W$. Define $Y=WX$. You can show $X,Y$ are uncorrelated and are marginally standard normal but not independent. However, two iid standard normals are also uncorrelated.

---

Here is a discrete example with *infinitely* many joint distributions that yield the same uncorrelated marginal distributions:

Suppose $X\in \{-1,0,1\}$ and $Y\in \{0,1\}$. For some $p\in (1/6,1/3)$, consider the joint distribution
$$\begin{align}
P(X=-1,Y=1)&=P(X=1,Y=1)=p,\\
P(X=-1,Y=0)&=P(X=1,Y=0)=1/3-p,\\
P(X=0,Y=0)&=2p-1/3\\
P(X=0,Y=1)&=2/3-2p\\
\end{align}
$$

The marginals are given by

$$P(X=x)=1/3 \quad \forall x\in \{-1,0,1\}\\
P(Y=0)=1/3,P(Y=1)=2/3$$

and $X,Y$ are uncorrelated (note $X$ has mean zero):

$$E[XY]=(-1)(1)p+(1)(1)p=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, this is insightful. Yes, correlation pins down only the second order. But this is very heuristic. The example is beautiful. However, I do not understand how $Y$ is standard normal. In the example, $a=1$, so yes. But for general $a$, the variance of $Y$ is $a^{2}$ if I am correct? Moreover, I have not been able to find any formal (book) treatment of the issues I am asking about. And if not results, then (counter-)examples. Maybe because questions about uniqueness/existence of a joint given marginals and other conditions seems to have distribution/parameter-specific answers.

Comment: @Jan You are right! Thanks for pointing out! I have updated the post to show a less ambitious counterexample, namely that the same marginals and correlation of zero can produce at least two joint distributions; also, the wiki link has another "asymmetric example" of uncorrelated standard normals. You may also be interested in [copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).

Comment: Thank you. I noticed copulas in some of my reading but did not pay much attention assuming that they apply to continuous r.v.s and I am mainly interested in discrete ones. I will keep educating myself.

Comment: @Jan I added a discrete example with infinitely many joint distributions--hope that helps.

Comment: The discrete example is great, and proves that my ''quest for uniqueness'' is bound to fail. Thanks for proving me wrong.